# Create feature task could not be completed because coordinates or measures are out of bounds?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, coordinate-system

I'm trying to create a layer based on a feature class, in ArcMap (I've created a geodatabase from ArcCatalog and linked it to PostgreSQL). The feature class that I've created is registered as versioned. I start editing and draw my polygons and when I finish sketch I get this error :

> The create feature task could not be completed. the coordinates or
>   measures are out of bounds.

```
My coordinate system is : Morocco North (Degrees)
Tolerance : 0.001 meters
XY Resolution : 0.0001 meters
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check the environments, namely processing extent of your project. Maybe while drawing a new feature, parts of it are founded out of extent bounds.

Comment: U mean the domain extent in the layer properties ? When I go there I have this 

XY Domain :
Max Y : 900691796974,099
Min Y : -28128500
Max X : 900682280674,099
Mix X : -37644800

Comment: And I cannot edit them by the way, since the feature class is already created

Comment: You will need to edit the extents of the feature class within ArcCatalog.

Comment: Not in layer but in the whole project: Geoprocessing > Environments > Processing Extent

Comment: I go there and I find Extent : Default. Should I choose instead : Same as display or which one exactly? And do I have to edit those values ? If so, what should I put and how would I make sure my drawings are not out of the extent bounds? Thank u both Erica and @mikhukh for ur responses

Comment: Try to define extents the same as in your edited fetura class. But firstly I would make sure that a coordinate system of your frame and your edited feature class are the same. Then I would compare extents of feature class and data frame. ArcGIS rarely returns bagreports in detail, so it is a little bit difficult to identify the problem for sure and at once..

Comment: I've tried what u suggested @mikhukh still the same error :(

Comment: I'm running into this today. What did you do to solve it?